# Summing and averaging in Casimir trick

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

For unpolarized particle scattering, we sum over the final particle spins and average over the initial spins. Why do we do so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because the incoming beam contains particles of all polarisations (average) and the outgoing particles can have any of the polarisations (sum).

In more detail:

When you perform an (unpolarised) scattering experiment you don't start with an individual incoming particle, but with a beam of particles. These particles can have any of the polarisations possible. So this is like a incoming particle with the average of all the polarisations. (Note: you can of course prepare a beam of particles with specific polarisations, but that is generally not the case, and then you don't call it unpolarised, obviously).

The outgoing particles can have, in principle any possible polarisation. So you need to take into account that you can make all these possible particles, hence sum over all the amplitudes. It may of course be possible that certain polarisations of outgoing particles are not possible, but then the corresponding amplitude will be zero and hence not contribute in the sum.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have explained in more detail. Hopefully this is clear now. If so, please accept the answer. Tx